# Finding PayPal transaction limits for currencies other than US dollars

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal's express checkout authorisation and capture API, the documentation describes the following limits.

AMT
(Required) Amount to capture.
Character length and limitations:
Value is typically a positive number that cannot exceed 10,000.00 USD

and

An authorization enables you to capture multiple payments up to 115% of, or USD $75 more than, the amount you specify in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment request.

I've spent a great deal of time looking as to what these limits would be in other currencies (specifically GBP) with no success. Does anyone know if these are documented somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

The limit for any other currency except for JPY is any amount in that currency that equivalent to 10,000 USD.

Comment: doesn't that change day to day ?